# minixml issue when the txt value contains space

Tags: c, xml, mini-xml, microxml

I have the following xml file:

```
<main>
    <tag>text with space</tag>
</main>
```

If I load the xml file in the mxml node tree with `mxmlLoadFile()`, then I will get 3 `MXML_TXT` childs under the `tag` MXML_ELEMENT. each child contains a substring.

- The first TXT child contains `"text"`
- The scond TXT child contains `"with"`
- The third TXT child contains `"space"`

I do not get only 1 child containing the whole string `"text with space"`

Are there a way (in the load) to have the whole string saved in only 1 child?

If not. Are there a function that return the whole string `"text with space"`?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer.

[C++: Trouble loading long string from XML file using Mini-XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974763/c-trouble-loading-long-string-from-xml-file-using-mini-xml)

I think you have to setup the MXML_OPAQUE_CALLBACK when you load the file. Then, instead of mxmlGetText, use mxmlGetOpaque.

Here are some more examples:

http://www.msweet.org/pipermail/mxml/2012-February/000081.html